# How to fill missing dates in report using sql or asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

I have the following sql table

```
name      date  clock in    clock out  
-----   -----   ---------   ----------  
csosa   01/01/2015  08:53:34    17:01:31  
csosa   01/02/2015  08:34:13    17:15:22  
csosa   01/04/2015  08:45:22    16:58:00  
....  
...
```

...

I have an asp.net page where the user selects a beginning date and and an end date and it generates a report just like the table above. What I would like to include in the report, are the missing dates from the results. As you can see there is no entry 
for 01/03/2015 meaning csosa didn't attend that day. I would like for the query to show something like this. So that the missing dates are included in the report

```
name    date    clock in    clock out  
-----   -----   ---------   ----------  
csosa   01/01/2015  08:53:34    17:01:31  
csosa   01/02/2015  08:34:13    17:15:22  
csosa   01/03/2015  ----        ----  
csosa   01/04/2015  08:45:22    16:58:00
```

How can I accomplish this using a store procedure or a query in sql where I pass in the beginning and end date as parameters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Carlos

Comment: Which `Database` you are using. **TAG** it accordingly please

Answer (score 0):

SQL query could look like this:

```
SELECT name, date, CASE
WHEN clock_in = NULL
THEN clock_in="----"
ELSE clock_in END as "Clock in",  CASE
WHEN clock_out = NULL
THEN clock_out="----"
ELSE clock_out END as "Clock out" from yourSqlTable 
WHERE date BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
```

OR in asp.net depending on what you are using for report viewing check if dataTable or Dataset's row.cells(colIndex).value=NULL; and replace it with "---" or anything you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a stored procedure and pass username, date range as parameters.

And your SP like this.

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATE = '01/01/2015',
       @ToDate DATE = '01/04/2015'

DECLARE @name VARCHAR(100) = 'csoa'

DECLARE @table TABLE(name VARCHAR(10), [date] DATE,  clockin TIME, clockout TIME)

INSERT INTO @table 

SELECT 'csoa', '01/01/2015', '08:53:34', '17:01:31' UNION
SELECT 'csoa', '01/02/2015', '08:34:13', '17:15:22' UNION
SELECT 'csoa', '01/04/2015', '08:45:22', '16:58:00' 

;WITH DateTable AS
(
  SELECT date1 =@FromDate, name =@name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(DD, 1, date1),@name FROM DateTable WHERE DATEADD(DD, 1, date1) <=@ToDate
)

SELECT DT.name, Dt.date1 as [date],

CASE WHEN clockin IS NULL THEN '--' ELSE CAST(clockin AS VARCHAR) END AS 'clock in', 
CASE WHEN clockout IS NULL THEN '--'ELSE CAST(clockout AS VARCHAR) END AS 'clock out' 

from  DateTable DT  LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT name, [date], clockin, clockout FROM @table 
WHERE [date] BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate 
)
 T  ON T.[date] = DT.date1
```

The @FromDate, @ToDate and @name are parameters from your ASP.Net application.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using a `Tally Table`. It's faster than the `Recursive CTE`. Read here for more info: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

```
DECLARE 
    @start  DATE = '20150101', -- Jan 1 2015
    @end    DATE = '20150115'  -- Jan 15 2015

;WITH E1(N) AS(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
)
,E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b)
,E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b)
,Tally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF(DAY, @start, @end) + 1) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM E4
)
,Dates AS(
    SELECT
        [Date] = DATEADD(DAY, N-1, @start)
    FROM Tally
    WHERE
        DATEADD(DAY, N-1, @start) <= @end
)
SELECT
    d.Date,
    t.ClockIn,
    t.ClockOut
FROM Dates d
LEFT JOIN Temp t
    ON t.Date = d.Date
WHERE d.Date BETWEEN @start AND @end -- You could actually remove this 
                                     -- since the dates have been filtered from the Tally CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
Declare @t table(name varchar(50),date1 date,clockin varchar(20),clockout varchar(20))  
insert into @t  values
('csosa','01/01/2015','08:53:34','17:01:31'  ),
('csosa','01/02/2015','08:34:13','17:15:22' ),
('csosa','01/04/2015','08:45:22','16:58:00' ) 

;With CTE as
(
 select *,row_number()over(order by date1)rn from @t 
)
,
CTE2 as
(
 select max(date1) maxdate from @t
)
,CTE1 as
(
 select NAME, date1 from cte where rn=1
union all
 select NAME, 
DATEADD(day,1,b.date1)
 from cte1 B
where b.date1<(select maxdate from CTE2)


)
select ISNULL(A.NAME,B.NAME)NAME
, B.DATE1
,ISNULL(A.clockin,'--') clockin
,ISNULL(A.clockout,'--') clockout 
from CTE1 B
LEFT JOIN cte a ON A.date1=B.date1
```